# How to make PHP script redirect and display a popup box simultaneously when something is true/successful?

Tags: javascript, php

In my PHP code, I have tried to make it so that after the user successfully sends an email, it redirects back to the contact page and then displays a popup box informing the user that the email has been successfully sent: however, the program only ever runs the top line, and does not run the popup box code. How do I fix this?

```js
<? php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: #';
$to = '#';
$subject = 'Customer Message - Online Form';
$body = "From: ".$name.
"\r\n E-Mail: ".$email.
"\r\n Message: \r\n".$message;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com.au');
    echo "<script>alert('Message successfully sent.');</script>";
  } else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are redirecting using your headers, if you try to echo first and then use header to redirect you will get an error, saying the headers are allready set.

You could add the redirect to your frontend, by returning something else like

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
       echo '<script>
            alert("Message successfully sent.");
            location.href="http://www.google.com.au";
      </script>';
   } else {
       echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
   }
}
```

the location redirect should wait for the alert to be dismissed, before executing

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting, by setting your header, before you print your alert. Try redirecting in the JS.

```
<? php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: #';
$to = '#';
$subject = 'Customer Message - Online Form';
$body = "From: ".$name.
"\r\n E-Mail: ".$email.
"\r\n Message: \r\n".$message;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Message successfully sent.'); window.location='http://www.google.com.au'</script>";
    //header('Location: http://www.google.com.au');
  } else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
  }
}

?>
```

**Note**

This will cause a JS alert before switching pages. If you want to alter on the page you land on you will want to send either a $_POST or $_GET variable and listen for it on the page you land on

Comment: you cant redirect with header after echoing

Comment: ok then do the redirect inside the js  instead (`window.location='http://www.google.com.au'`)

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Did you really utilize my solution and give someone else credit for it?

Comment: i just said that you cant echo before header changes. and gave point to you, not the other guy...

Comment: oh sorry.. thought you were OP

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect the user away from the page and expect the page to still display something to the user.

If you want to display a message on a different page than store it in session and then, on the other page, check if something is stored in session and display that.